# trigger with multiple action and loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, triggers

I have 3 tables in my database.

**- train_information

 - axle

 - bogie**

When i fill in a form, the information gets filled in the `train_information` table, and looks like this then:

[image: train_information table]

Now, you see the `number_of_axles` is 4.

The tables `axle` and `bogie` look like this.

**Axle**: 
[image: axle table]

**Bogie**:[image: bogie table]

As you can see, a trigger inserts 3 wich it should for the axle table only. But in the bogie table, i want to add 4.
Here a example:

[image: How i want it to be]

This all needs to be in 1 trigger aswell. because mysql version does not support multiple triggers with the same action (After insert).

The axle trigger is already working. This is how it looks:

[image: The axle trigger]

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: What is `axle_nr` in bogie table how its value is calculated ?

Comment: In the train_information table, you see 4 axles. I want those to be placed in the bogie table in the axle_nr row. just like it is now, but then 1 more. So the axle_nr in the bogie table is the number of axles of the train information table.

Comment: So you can create one trigger AFTER INSERT in train_information and then another one BEFORE INSERT in the Bogie table to check if exists. Well, if that is your problem cuz I don't really get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to add another loop inside the existing trigger as

```
delimiter //
create trigger train_information_ins after insert on train_information
for each row 
begin
 declare x int ;
 declare y int ;
 if(new.number_of_axies >  0 ) then
   set x = 1 ;
   while x < new.number_of_axies do
     insert into axle (train_id,axle)
     values
     (new.train_id,x);
     set x=x+1;
    end while ;

    set y=1;
    while y <= new.number_of_axies do
      insert into bogie (train_id,axle_nr)
      values
      (new.train_id,y); 
       set y=y+1;
     end while ; 
  end if ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```